# std:forward inside a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

```
 template<typename T>
   class BlockingQueue
   { 
       std::queue<T> container_;

       template< typename U >
       void push(U&& value)
       {
           static_assert(std::is_same<T, typename std::remove_reference<U>::type>::value,"Can't call push without the same parameter as template parameter's class");

           container_.push(std::forward<U>(value)); 
       }
};
```

I would like BlockingQueue::push method be able to handle both rvalue and lvalue reference of object of type T to forward it to  `std::queue::push` correct version.
Is it preferable to do like the above code, or to provide two versions of push method inside my `BlockingQueue` class ? One for lvalue and one for rvalue

Comment: I'd write two overloads, one for `T const &` and one for `T &&`...

Comment: The above is called "perfect forwarding" and it handles both lvalues and rvalues just fine. I'd keep it that way. (@KerrekSB Hm, does this mean this Q is primarily opinion based? ;)

Comment: @DanielFrey: Call it whatever you want, but if you combine argument deduction with immediate `is_same` constraint on the type itself, I think you're trying to be too clever. If you want a `T`, just make overloads for `T`. It's shorter and easier to read and diagnose.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's actually quite true, I didn't paid any attention to that `static_assert` as my mind simply skipped it as "superfluous" and I would've removed it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I completely agree with your argument and that's exactly the point of my post.

Comment: the `static_assert` seems wrong. Don't you want to support const values? What you really should be checking is `is_convertible<U,T>::value`. Another way of handling this would be `enable_if` instead of a static assertion. `enable_if` has the advantage that you can kick the function pretty early from the overload set to avoid ambiguities and to let the compiler point to the offending user code instead.

Comment: @sellibitze: you right but as saying by others it is preferable to have two version of push function (one for rvalue and one for lvalue)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation seems correct to me and does the job.

Nevertheless, providing different implementations for lvalues and rvalues might be a good idea in your case. The main reason (that I can think of) is that deduction of template type arguments doesn't work for *braced-init-lists*. Consider:

```
struct foo {
    foo(std::initializer_list<int>) {
    }
};

// ...
foo f{1, 2, 3};    // OK

BlockingQueue<foo> b;
```

With the OP's code (*)

```
b.push(f);         // OK
b.push({1, 2, 3}); // Error
```

If instead, the following overloads of `BlockingQueue::push` are provided:

```
void push(const T& value) {
    container_.push(value); 
}

void push(T&& value) {
    container_.push(std::move(value)); 
}
```

Then the line that used to fail will work fine.

The same arguments apply to aggregates. For instance, if `foo` was defined as

```
struct foo {
    int a, b, c;
};
```

one would observe the same behaviors described above.

My conclusion is that, if you want `BlockingQueue` to support more types (including aggregates or types with constructors taking `std::initializer_list`s), then it's better to provide two different overloads.

(*) A small correction in the OP's code: in the `static_assert` you need to use `typename`

```
typename std::remove_reference<U>::type>::value
^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Is http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2812.html#impact-on-the-standard-library another reason to provide different implementation to lvalue and rvalues?

Comment: @ViniciusMiranda: The problem mentioned in the paper dates back to 2008 when move semantics was still being designed. By reading the paper I deduced that back then rvalue references could be bound to lvalues. The paper suggests to forbid this binding and that's what was adopted in C++11. So this danger no longer exists. My main problem (there might be others that I don't see) with the single implementation taking a universal reference is, as I said in the post, the impossibility to deduce the type of *braced-init-lists* because they don't have a type (they are just syntax contructs).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use perfect forwarding, then I suggest you use `emplace` method of `queue` class. `emplace` method forwards given argument to `T` constructor. There will be no need to check whether `T` is same as `U`. It should compile as long as `T` is constructable from `U`. Moreover, you can use variadic template arguments if you wish.

```
template<typename... Args>
void push(Args&&... args)
{
    container_.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Therefore, you can push whatever you want, as long as T is constructable from the given arguments.